# Here it is: why don't they use "lo" in the answer?

Tags: pronouns

I am listening to some Italian Language tapes to learn Italian.  They are having a conversation about coffee and sugar, etc., and one of them is supposed to say "Yes, here it is" (regarding the sugar) in Italian.  The response on the tape is;

"Sì, ecco."
Why isn't it the following? "Sì, eccolo."

(lo zucchero)

Comment: It's optional. There's no need for the tag like in English.

Comment: Would "Sì,  eccolo" be correct if I wanted to use it?

Comment: Yes, certainly.

Comment: Note that in Italian even "here" is optional :) (you can say *Ecco qua* or *Ecco qui*)

Comment: Oh, had not thought of that...  So ecco is really a pretty useful all around word.

Comment: If you want a little more confusion, it Italian is also possible to say: *Eccotelo qua!". But it is not a correct way to write such a sentence.

Comment: Also you could be less polite and just say "qua!" same as an English would say "here!".... hows that for confusion ;) ?

Comment: @Denis  - Why would I say qua instead of qui?  I think I like the sound of   Eccoci qua!

Comment: @Msfolly It sounds more natural to me too, but both are correct. I think that *Eccoci qua* is preferable to *Eccoci qui* in order to differentiate the final vowel, but as I said this is a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[Ecco](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/E/ecco.php)*** : (adv.) is used to indicate that something or someone is coming. Personal pronouns  can be added to the expression:

> - ***Si usa per richiamare l'attenzione su qualcuno o qualcosa che sopraggiunge, che sta per accadere e simili***: *Ecco  la mamma che arriva; ecco, vengo!; ecco che mi torna la febbre.*
> - ***Può essere unito ai pronomi personali  atoni*** mi, ti, si, ci, vi, lo, la, li, le e ne in posizione encl.: *eccoci qua!; eccomi!; eccone uno!*

(Hoepli)